# Starting a bash script from a php script

Tags: php, bash, nginx, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a bash script using shell_exec but It doesnt seem to work. (Nothing seems to happen) I'm using nginx and the latest php5-cgi. Heres what the php file looks like:

```
<?php

$startserver = "./startserver.sh";
$startserver = shell_exec($startserver);
$getprocess = "pidof hlds_amd";
$pid = shell_exec($getprocess);

$fh = fopen('closeserver.sh', 'w');
$command = "kill -9 $pid";
fwrite($fh, $command);
fclose($fh);


$string = "at -f closeserver.sh now + 1 hour";
$closer = shell_exec($string);  


?>
```

and this is what the bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/kraffs/srcds
./hlds_run -game cstrike -autoupdate +maxplayers 12 +map de_dust2 > hlds.log 2>&1 &
```

Theres no errors in the phpscript and the file gets created just fine but $startserver doesnt seem to get executed and $pid is empty. Did I miss something in the php file or do I need to change permissions for an user? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace shell_exec, with below function and try again

```
<?php
function runcmd($EXEC_CMD)

    $handle = popen ($EXEC_CMD, 'r');
    $output = "";
    if ($handle) {
        while(! feof ($handle)) {
            $read = fgets ($handle);
            $output .= $read;
        } 
        pclose($handle);
    }
    return $output;
}  
?>
```

Comment: yeah, it should be a blank page because you didnt print out any output, if you like to see the output, append **echo $output;** before **return $output;** in runcmd function. In additon insert **<pre>** before your first **<?php** tag and **</pre>** after your last **?>** tag. make sure that you have **chmod +x startserver.sh**, insert **runcmd("chmod +x closeserver.sh");** before **$closer = shell_exec($string);**

Comment: I did, it says nothing and does nothing.

Comment: I even tried changing to apache2 and It didn't work there either.

Comment: is your startserver.sh is located in the same folder with the phpscript? is your hlds.log empty? does display_error turn on in your php.ini? if so, this is as far as I can help

Comment: It doesnt even exist :( "$startserver = "./startserver.sh";
runcmd($startserver);" doesnt seem to do anything at all. startserver.sh works fine in bash but doesnt seem to work when I try to execute it from the .php file.

Comment: I think I found something, the php script uses www-data as the user. ./startserver.sh: line 3: hlds.log: Permission denied

Comment: quick and dirty: chmod -R 777 <hlds folder> :D, this is not secured, and may cause another problem,but it may help you run your script while finding another way around, you may need root (or sudo) privileges to do chmod or chown. You may try: sudo chown -R yourname:www-data <hlds folder>